# Подскажите какой стек технологий использовать?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-development

Всем привет! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Необходимо написать приложение, но не знаю как его реализовать. Суть проста: обычные шахматные задачи. Юзер на доске должен делать ходы перетаскивая фигуры на ячейки. И еще такая фишка, если юзер 3 раза неправильно ходит, приложение показывает подсказку. Так как я нуб, не знаю что учить и в каком направлении двигаться. Скрины с прототипом прилагаю. Заранее спасибо, друзья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что указали в тегах, то и используйте. Устанавливаете XCode, изучаете Swift. Разбиваете задачу вашу на мелкие подзадачи и решаете в учебном процессе: работа в Interface Builder для проектирования дизайна экрана, назначение событий, перетаскивание объектов, алгоритмы ходов и т.д. Можно предварительно ознакомиться с каким-либо учебным курсом по Swift, где представлена разработка тестового приложения от и до. Если вообще не программировали до этого, то изучаете базовые понятия - переменная, цикл, функция и т.д.

Comment: Я уже знаю Swift,  изучил все классы UIKit. Вопрос в том как реализовать шахматную доску. Через SpriteKit может?

Comment: Скажу честно, со SpriteKit дела не имел, но перетаскивание фигур можно реализовать и обычной анимацией вью, используя `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)` с анимацией фреймов или `CGAffineTransform`

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Хорошего дня Вам!

Comment: И вам . Если ответ устраивает, отметьте галочку слева от него